# Crashlytics does not display custom log entries in the Firebase Console

Tags: android, firebase, crashlytics-android

I've integrated `Firebase Crashlytics` into my app as per Googles instructions:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/get-started

My problem is when I try to do custom logging such as:

```
Crashlytics.log("testing");
Crashlytics.log(Log.ERROR, TAG, "testing");
Crashlytics.getInstance().crash();
```

In `Firebase Console` I get the crash stack callback (as expected) BUT only one (probably the first) log entry from the first `Crashlytics.log` call done (not the ones above however).

I've waited 48h to see if there's a delay but nothing appears.

It works fine when I "force" the crash in the emulator.

I also tried `new RuntimeException()` instead of `Crashlytics.getInstance().crash()`

I am calling the `Crashlytics` functions in a library which is included in my app(s).

Comment: have you checked after restarting the app ?

Comment: Why aren't you checking Crashlytics console instead of firebase?

Comment: (1) Yep I checked after I've restarted the app.
(2) When using Crashalytics Console I need an API key. But when I have an API key I cannot get it in Firebase Console. Also I prefer to have "everything" collected in the Firebase Console. Besides it should work in Firebase Console also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mike from Firebase here. Crashlytics prioritizes capturing crashes over writing custom keys or logs as crashes are more important to capture. Once a crash happens, we need to act as quickly as possible to get the exact state of the device and all the threads running. Things are still changing and happening after a crash, so to get the most accurate stack trace, if a key or log has not been written out, we will drop that and capture the crash instead.

Given that the log you're not seeing is happening just before the crash occurs, I would expect the log closest to the crash to be ignored. When using custom logs and keys, it's best to log them as early as you can, for example when an activity changes. As a side note, for non-test crashes, this is usually not an issue since you don't know in advance where the crash will occur in your app.

Comment: I want to know the status of the SW leading up to a particular function using Crashlytics.log. In that function I create a crash so I can see the log in the console. 

The crash is only on a particular phone which I don't have physically (i.e one of my testers got it). So I use Crashlytics to remotely "debug" the crash. 

Perhaps it could be enough for me to delay the Crashlytics.getInstance().crash() call with a few ms?

Comment: I am thinking that perhaps in specific debug scenarios where other threads are not so important, the log might be more important. Thus would it not be good with a specific option to always be sure the logs has been "flushed"?

Comment: Yes, if you have a specific user you need to diagnose an issue on, then delaying the crash 10-20ms should do it. Right now, no plans to add in a configurable option for ensuring that the keys/logs are written before the crash, but will share the feedback with the team.

Comment: After the delay it worked just fine. Although the problem is that if I delay the crash using Handler.postDelayed() the stack trace won't be correct since it will be relative to the thread executing .crash() later. 

Please share the feedback with the team. In certain scenarios I can certainly see the need to be completely sure the log has been flushed. 

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Does it work like this for non-fatals too? If it does, then it makes firebase logging practically useless as a debugging method...

Comment: The logging behavior is the same regardless of the exception type. The key thing to note is that when an exception happens, processes and threads continue to run albeit now in a less healthy state. In order to capture the most accurate stack trace, we need to capture it as soon as possible. If we wait to finish capturing the key or log, then the stack trace is less accurate and that's not ideal.

Comment: Fabric had this option. I don't need to know that my app caught an exception to see the logs. Fabric used to show all logs for the app crashes?!

Comment: Crashlytics isn't made for develop logging, it is made to cluster hundreds/thousands of logs from different users at runtime, this may cause that the dashboard doesn't show the logs in the exactly time they are produced.

If you want to use Crashlytics to follow the code workflow and debug during development, you will need to use the trick in this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/69340289/5679560