# Force FirebaseCrashlytics print logs to console

Tags: crashlytics, crashlytics-android, firebase-crash-reporting

Is it possible to force `FirebaseCrashlytics` to print the log messages to console prior google buy them (and make shit as always) it was possible using the fabric api. But now seems these methods were removed.

Is there any way to do for the android sdk?

Answer (score 2):

**Short Answer**
IT IS IMPOSSIBLE (USING FIREBASECRASHLYTICS SDK)

**Complete Answer**
It is a shame that prior to Google buys Crashlytics, watch the log messages on development console was an easy task to do. But now these methods were removed.

The whole problem is, if I'm in the development environment and want to follow the code execution (by watching the log messages) Crashlytics won't show them... I need to intentionally cause an crash, then wait a time for it be uploaded to dashboard them start hunting for the registers among maybe thousands of others... (non sense)

I filled a bug report for firebase

https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/3005

For those who don't want wait to google fix their shit there is a workaround:

```
FirebaseApp.initializeApp(this);

        if (BuildConfig.DEBUG) {
            try {
                Field f = FirebaseCrashlytics.class.getDeclaredField("core");
                f.setAccessible(true);


                CrashlyticsCore core = (CrashlyticsCore) f.get(FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance());
                f = CrashlyticsCore.class.getDeclaredField("controller");
                f.setAccessible(true);

                Object controler = f.get(core);
                f = controler.getClass().getDeclaredField("logFileManager");
                f.setAccessible(true);


                f.set(controler, new LogFileManager(null, null) {
                    @Override
                    public void writeToLog(long timestamp, String msg) {
                        super.writeToLog(timestamp, msg);
                        System.out.println(msg);
                    }
                });


                FirebaseCrashlytics.getInstance().log("test");

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }
```

The code above is replacing  the field that was supposed to write the log messages to a file (AND ACTUALLY DOES NOTHING) by a new class which does all the previous one (NOTHING) but prints on the fly all messages logged.

**ATTENTION**
I've tested this on `firebase-analytics:19.0.1` and this will only on versions of the lib with the same fields names
**IT WON'T WORK IN OBFUSCATED BUILD**, if you obfuscate the code in DEBUG mode the code will break (unless you add the proper rules to proguard)

If this topic reaches google engineers is very likely they will remove/obfuscate the code for next versions

google...